# Call hosted WCF service from php

Tags: php, .net, wcf, web-services

I have a **WCF web service**, made in .net framework 4.0.

The service is hosted on **IIS 7**.

Then i have a **WAMP server** for PHP.

How can a page made in **PHP call the WCF service** functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried?

You can use the `SoapClient` [as shown here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2007/09/17/using-wcf-services-with-php.aspx):

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://gamma/wcftest/MathService.svc?wsdl');
$obj->x = 2.5;
$obj->y = 3.5;
$retval = $client->Add($obj);

echo "2.5 + 3.5 = " . $retval->AddResult;
```

Comment: I have a function like 
List<Admins> GetAdmins(int Cid)

Comment: I'm on php4.. and havent used soapclient

Comment: PHP5 is now 9 years old. Upgrade your development server or switch hosting provider.

Comment: @CodeCaster, sometimes the project is so big that doing that is not easy or even possible (budget problem).    
He can have a client with an big old project, done in php4 running on and old machine for years, inhouse.    
Maybe a lot of the client's business runs on that project. And maybe there is not enough money to adapt/rewrite the entire thing in PHP5.  
I've seen cases like that.    
There are thing on the real world that make the "i'll just apt-get upgrade and it's done" solution not a realistic one.

Comment: @osiris of course it can happen, I've seen it too. If you can't convince the client that they need a rewrite of (parts of) their application to allow for future development, you try to create the newer parts using newer frameworks that do support the functionality you want to use. If you don't, you can't keep up and you'll lose huge amounts of time, your client and/or your business. "It's too much work" is never an excuse, it's a matter of priorities.

Comment: @CodeCaster, true. i fully agree with you. but sometimes the functionality (and the budget) is small enough :) i guess, like we both know, it always depends on the specific case. oh well...

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what language front end is or what language it is being called from.

That is the beauty of web service, it gives you platform independency.

WCF return data in JSON, JSONP or XML and all can be consumed in your PHP, jQuery, Java, etc...

You just have to learn how to consume the chosen format of returned data.

Comment: Thanks Nipun, but i already know that web service can be called from any platform. But How to specifically call one from php?